# use sysdate as parameter to insert into database

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a prepareStatement that inserts a date value into the test table.
The date value can be the value from a parameter or NULL.
Now I want to insert the sysdate in database if the date value is null.
I don't want to use `new java.util.Date().getTime()` since the time in my PC may not be the same as the time in database.

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    boolean rs = false;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO test (ID, record_date values(?, ?)";

        pstmt = DBConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, para1);
        if (para2 != null)
           pstmt.setDate(2, para2);
        else
          pstmt.setDate(2, sysdate); // is that possible?

        rs = (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boolean rs = false;
String sql = "INSERT INTO test (ID, record_date) values(?, NVL(?, sysdate()))";
PreparedStatement pstmt = DBConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, para1);
if (para2 == null)
    pstmt.setNull(2, Types.Date);
else
    pstmt.setDate(2, para2);
rs = (pstmt.executeUpdate() > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't possible. if you want to use the date from the db you have to use:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO test (ID, record_date values(?, systdate())";
```